# L¹ norm of Riesz potentials on flat tori

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory

Let $g$ be the distribution whose Fourier coefficients are given by
$$\hat{g}(k) = \begin{cases} 0, & {k=0} \\ |k|^{s-d}, & {k\in \mathbb{Z}^d\setminus\{0\}},\end{cases} \qquad 0\leq s<d,$$
that is the unique solution to
$$(-\Delta)^{\frac{d-s}{2}}g = \delta_0 - 1.$$
We will call $g$ the *periodic Riesz potential* of order $d-s$. It is known (I don't have a ref at the top of my mind) that $g\in L^1(\mathbb{T}^d)$, $g$ is $C^\infty$ away from the origin, and the difference
$$g(x)-c_{d,s}|x|^{-s} \in C^\infty(B(0,1/4)), \qquad c_{d,s} := 2^{s-d}\pi^{-d/2}\frac{\Gamma(s/2)}{\Gamma((d-s)/2)}, \ 0<s<d,$$
$$g(x)+c_d\log|x|\in C^\infty(B(0,1/4)), \qquad c_d:=\frac{2}{(4\pi)^{d/2}\Gamma(d/2)}, \ s=0.$$
Here, I am identifying the torus with the cube $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]^d$ under periodic boundary conditions.

> **Question.** Is there an exact formula for the $L^1$ norm $\|g\|_{L^1(\mathbb{T}^d)}$? I'm really only interested in the case
> $s=0$, so I would be happy with just an answer for this case.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, $g$ is simply the periodization of the usual RIesz kernel $c_{d,s}|x|^{-s}$. I do not think, though, that a reasonable expression for $\|g\|_1$ is possible when $d \geqslant 2$. Already the description of the set $\{g < 0\}$ is problematic, I believe. And I the logarithmic case $s = 0$ is does not seem any simpler.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks for your comment, Mateusz! I might be wrong, but I don't think one can directly show the periodization is a convergent series in general, since in the case $s<d$, the Riesz potential on $\mathbb{R}^d$ does not decay fast enough.